# Renaming File Paths and Doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a file that is located at a different path at development time, however at the time of release it will be in a different location. The title of the documentation, after being generated, is set to the development path. Is it possible to manually set the path of the filename?

What I mean about title:
The structure of the documented source file is:
\File\Path\Filename.cpp [Title]
Function prototypes
… (other documented aspects)

For example the file is located at `c:\Code\Dev\Filename.cpp` during development and during release it is located at `c:\SuperFantasticApplication\Code\Filename.cpp`.

I’ve tried adding a parameter after the filename at the top of the file (\file [name I want it to be]). However, that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option in doxygen to turn of using full path names in the documentation. Inside your doxygen configuration file set `FULL_PATH_NAMES` to `NO`.

Here's what the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_full_path_names) says about it:

> If the FULL_PATH_NAMES tag is set to
>   YES  doxygen will prepend the full
>   path before files name in the file
>   list and in the header files. If set
>   to NO the shortest path that makes the
>   file name unique will be used